# give values to a subroutine in batch

Tags: batch-file, subroutine

I want to give a batch file subroutine two values. I thought it would work like this:

```
CALL :mail %from% %to%
```

and the subroutine looks like:

```
:mail
blat.exe -to %2 -f %1
```

%2 because it is the second argument that I give to that subroutine. And %1 because it's the first one. Or am I think wrong at this point?

Comment: You're right. So, what's the question?`- You could easily test it.

Comment: I have tested it. And it fails. So is there a better way? A way that works? :)

Comment: How does it fail? Whats the output when calling the batch file? Tried adding a `pause` or `echo`statements for debugging?

Comment: Yes, in fact subroutines works like calling a separate batch file.You can use `"%~1"` ,`"%~2"` to robust your code - ~ is for dequote , and additional quotes are for dealing with spaces.

Comment: Are you setting %from% and %to% values inside FOR loop? If yes may be you'll need delayed expansion?

Comment: Nope, it is set at the beginning of the script, before the loop. Thanks for your comments.